# Factory girl has_many

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rspec

How i can create object with association

I have `Post` model and `PostsPhoto`

```
  PostsPhoto => belongs_to :post
  Post => has_many :post_photos, dependent: :destroy,class_name: 'PostsPhoto'
```

I have tried

```
 FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    article Faker::Lorem.paragraph(4)
    video 'http://youtube.com'
    author Faker::Name.name
    category 'article'
    title Faker::Name.title
    post_photos
  end
end
```

and have got

```
  NoMethodError: undefined method `each' for #<PostsPhoto:0x007ff68e3bd698>
```

i cant use `after(:create) {}`,because i validate it on create

```
  def check_slider_photo
    errors.add(:post_photos, 'Add post photos') if self.post_photos.size <= 0
  end
```

I want to `create(:post)=> returns me post object with post_photos`

Answer (score 0):

There are a couple ways around this. It depends on what you're testing exactly, but if you don't need to alter the objects or use them in queries, try using `build_stubbed` instead of `create`.

That is, if you'd typically say, `FactoryGirl.create(:post)`, try instead saying `FactoryGirl.build_stubbed(:post)`.

Another option would be not to run your validation in test and test that validation separately. To do this you can say

```
post = FactoryGirl.build(:post)
post.save(validate: false)
```

Then create the other objects and pass them `post.id` Happy testing.

Comment: i need it for my integration tests so all objects should be created

Comment: Especially for integration tests...test the validation separately in a unit test.

Comment: ye,separately,but i want to use this factory for unit tests also, so hack with skipping validation is bad idea.i guess

Comment: welp. it'll work. Is that validation really necessary? Seems like an odd validation, anyway. You're validating the child objects exist when the parent is created? But...tangent. If you believe it is necessary, you could use fixtures instead of factory girl and pass specific ids so they pre-exist.

Comment: no i validate it before save with `validate :check_slider_photo` i want to be sure that post cant be created without post_photos

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :post do
    article Faker::Lorem.paragraph(4)
    video 'http://youtube.com'
    author Faker::Name.name
    category 'article'
    title Faker::Name.title

    factory :post_with_photos do
      ignore do
        photos_count 3
      end

      after(:build) do |post, evaluator|
        post.post_photos << build_list(:post_photo, evaluator.photos_count)
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Comment: it didn't pass my validation `validate :check_slider_photo `

Comment: If you run `post = build(:post)` and inspect the value immediately after with `post.post_photos` – are there any photos being built? You might want to check that each of those is valid as well – e.g. `post.post_photos.first.valid?`